# Download images from webpage

Tags: python, web, download, scripting

i've tried to download images from a webpage, what am i missing here please ?

```
    import urllib
    from urllib.request import urlopen, Request 
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import os

urlpage ='https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1414&bih=709&q=little+cofee'
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}  
page = urlopen(Request(urlpage,headers=header))
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

images = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"thumb-pic"})
for image in images:
     imgUrl = image.a['href'].split("imgurl=")[1]
     urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgUrl, os.path.basename(imgUrl))
```

Comment: There are no html tags in page source of the given url with class as thumb-pic.

Comment: @Vikas Neha Ojha  what should i do ?

Comment: Try looking at the original page source and find out how the image urls are being sent. Open this in chrome: - view-source:https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1414&bih=709&q=little+cofee

Comment: @Vikas Neha Ojha i tried to use "class":"rg_i" but i get nothing maybe there's an error with the for loop ?

Comment: Whenever you want to check if there is a problem with loop, print the contents of *images* before the loop.

Comment: @Vikas Neha Ojha ok thanks for your help, but i'm not good enought i really tried i don't know what to do

Comment: An alternative approach. Instead of looking for a `div` tag, search for an `a` tag and then check the href values for a link ending in jpg or other well known image types.  You might grab a few of googles page images but you'd probably get all the images from the image search.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky. Sometimes they use short URLs like "images/img.jpg", "/images/img.jpg", "../images/img.jpg". But the google page you are trying has no html tags at all. It contains just javascript.

I made a quick and dirty example just to show you how it might work in Python 2.7 but you can just save the page opened in your browser and all images will be saved neatly in a folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib

url ='http://www.blogto.com/cafes/little-nickys-coffee-toronto'
ext=['.jpg', '.png', '.gif'] # image type to download

response= urllib.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()

IMGs=[]
L=html.split('src="')
for item in L:
    item=item[:item.find('"')]
    item=item.strip()
    if item.find('http') == -1:
        item=url[:url.find('/', 10)]+item
    for e in ext:
        if item.find(e) != -1:
            if item not in IMGs:
                IMGs.append(item)


n=len(IMGs)
print 'Found', n, 'images'
i=1
for img in IMGs:
    ext=img[img.rfind('.'):]
    filename='0'*(len(str(n))-len(str(i)))+str(i)
    i += 1
    try:
        print img
        f = open(filename+ext,'wb')
        f.write(urllib.urlopen(img).read())
        f.close()
    except:
        print "Unpredictable error:", img

print 'Done!'
```